# Why are there two <Command> + I shortcuts in preview?

Tags: keyboard, macos, preview, shortcut

I'm used to using Preview for simple edits to images - cropping, censoring, highlighting, rotating - and I try to use shortcuts as much as possible. Previously I would use <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> to show the inspector. A while ago I noticed it wasn't working. Upon further investigation I noticed that <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> also invoked the `Show/Hide Toolbar` command.

Why are there two shortcuts for the same menu command, and is there any way I can change this for my macs I use regularly?

This is OS X 10.11.6, if it matters. Preview 8.1 (877.7).

[image: Show Inspector]

[image: Hide Toolbar]

---

Edit to add info: I have no app defined keyboard shortcuts except for "help", see below screenshot...

[image: Keyboard Shortcuts]

Answer (score 1):

Because you (or someone else) change it in keyboard shortcuts.

Check your Keyboard shortcuts..

It should be

[image]

and

[image]

Comment: I have no keyboard shortcuts defined for this app (Preview), and no general shortcuts except for "help". See update to question.

Comment: I believe you did not knowingly do it. It could have been some app you are using. Anyway, toss the preview Preferences list and let it build a new one.

Comment: I can do that ... where is the Preferences list located?

Comment: `ls ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Preview.*` gives 
`/Users/me/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Preview.LSSharedFileList.plist`
`/Users/me/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Preview.SandboxedPersistentURLs.LSSharedFileList.plist` ... nothing about keyboard shortcuts. Which file should I trash?

Comment: ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Preview.plist

Comment: See my last comment; there is no `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Preview.plist`.

Comment: ups, sorry, you are on El Capitan. I do not know where it is there.

Comment: Pathname to Preview prefs file is : `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Preview/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Preview.plist` because it's a sandboxed app.